# .htaccess force non-www to www with single page exception

Tags: .htaccess, exception, redirect

We've successfully forced all pages in the site to use WWW using the following code:

```
##### Redirect non-www to www -- BEGIN
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/TEST_SITE/$1 [R=301,L]
##### Redirect non-www to www -- END
```

But our registration page is an exception that has to use a URL that doesn't include the WWW. Two days of testing and research and the only thing I can produce are errors and infinite loops. Does anyone have a suggestion for forcing all pages to WWW except this one page?

```
http://mysite.com/TEST_SITE/component/users/?view=registration
```

It seems like it should use a simple redirect before the general WWW redirect, but I can't find a comparable solution in the forums. I'm grateful for any ideas....

Comment: then you need another rewritecond to match/exclude whatever the registration url is.

Answer (score 0):

```
#strip www from registration page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=registration$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^TEST_SITE/component/users/$ http://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

# prevent adding www to registration page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=registration$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^TEST_SITE/component/users/$ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/TEST_SITE/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This looks (to my uneducated eye) like it should work, but it just won't recognize the registration page link as separate from the other pages requiring the WWW. UGH!

Comment: so you want to strip the www from registration page? answer updated

Comment: Yes, everything EXCEPT the registration page should have the www. The registration page should look like http://mysite.com/TEST_SITE/component/users/?view=registration.

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone have a suggestion for forcing all pages to WWW except this one page `http://mysite.com/TEST_SITE/component/users/?view=registration` Yes you can.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !view=registration
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/TEST_SITE/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Just add a new condition.

Comment: Like Amine's answer, this one seems like it should work but the Query_String isn't identifying the page and converting it to a non-www address.

Comment: You can try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/TEST_SITE/component/users/$` if you didn't willing to redirect http://mysite.com/TEST_SITE/component/users/ or check `RewriteCond /TEST_SITE/component/users/%{QUERY_STRING} !view=registration` IF IT'S POSSIBLE..